# How to echo a PID in front of every prompt message from the background process in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a main shell file `main.sh`, and numerous background subshell files all called by execution. These files are `a.sh`, `b.sh`, `c.sh`...

I am calling these subshell files in the main such as the following:

```
#main.sh
./a.sh &
./b.sh &
./c.sh &
```

In each of the background subshell file, the format looks like the following

```
#a.sh
echo "This is a process"
```

the subshells are almost identical, the output messages are necessary for my task but it is hard to identify which messages correspond to which subshell process. I am thinking of assigning them an PID and prepend that PID to the messages output from each of the subshell.
This looks like the following:

```
[123]This is a process
[234]This is a process
...
```

Thanks!

**EDIT** It would be great to enable this feature in the main.sh instead of modify the subshell process since I only want to see them some times for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just launch them like so?

```
./a.sh | sed 's/^/[a] /' &
./b.sh | sed 's/^/[b] /' &
./c.sh | sed 's/^/[c] /' &
```

or even if you really want to include the PID:

```
./a.sh | sed "s/^/[$!] /" &
./b.sh | sed "s/^/[$!] /" &
./c.sh | sed "s/^/[$!] /" &
```

should work.

Comment: `$!` isn't the process ID of `a.sh`, because the pipeline hasn't been backgrounded yet.

Comment: @chepner are you sure? `:)` what is it then?

Comment: It's the process ID of the last background process. At the time it is expanded, `a.sh` is not yet a background process, because it hasn't been started yet. When you start `b.sh`, `$!` will be the process ID of the background process that is running `a.sh`, and so on.

Comment: @chepner can you prove what you're saying, or would `sleep 100 | echo "hello: $!" &` be a good enough proof?

Comment: Huh. I figured the `&` was processed after `$!` was expanded. Apparently, a process is allocated by the `&` before the command line to execute in that process is expanded, so `$!` does in fact refer to background command in which it appears.

Comment: @chepner Yep, I was sure you overlooked the `&`... `:)`

Comment: I didn't overlook it; I just failed to understand the order in which the full command line was evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$$` contains the current PID.

```
echo "[$$]This is a process"
```

Comment: But instead of modify each of the subshell process, can I do that in the main.sh? I want to enable this feature only sometimes.

Comment: You can pipe the output of the command to a `sed` command that adds a prefix. But you can't get the child's PID until after the background process is started, so you can't substitute it into the command.

Comment: `$$` is always the process ID of the parent shell; use `$BASHPID` if available (in 4 or later).

Comment: @chepner My answer was intended to go in `a.sh`, `b.sh`, etc. where `$$` would be the PID of that shell.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be the actual process ID, but just a unique identifier, you can set a known environment variable:

```
#main.sh
MY_ID=1 ./a.sh &
MY_ID=2 ./b.sh &
MY_ID=3 ./c.sh &

#a.sh
echo "[$MY_ID]This is a process"
```

In `bash` 4 or later, you can access the process ID of a shell with `$BASHPID`, so that you
don't need to specify a `MY_ID` when you launch each background process.

```
#a.sh
echo "[$BASHPID]This is a process"
```

If you want to automatically prepend every line of output with the identifier, you'll need to define a wrapper for `echo` instead of using it directly:

```
my_echo () { echo "[$MY_ID]$*"; }
my_echo () { echo "[$BASHPID]$*"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bash wrapper function called "echo" and export it, so your background scripts use this overriding version:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat bgscript
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}; do echo "i=$i"; done

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ function echo { builtin echo "[$$]$@"; }
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ export -f echo
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./bgscript &
[1] 7290
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ [7290]i=1
[7290]i=2
[7290]i=3

[1]+  Done                    ./bgscript
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something like this using [bash coprocesses](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) (bash 4 required). The code would go like:

```
prepend_pid() {
    coproc "${@}"
    pid=${!}
    trap "kill ${pid}" EXIT
    sed -e "s:^:${pid} :" </dev/fd/${COPROC[0]}
}

prepend_pid ./a.sh &
prepend_pid ./b.sh &
prepend_pid ./c.sh &
```

This is because you need to meet two goals:

1. You need to fork the script first to know its PID,
2. You need to redirect the script output before forking it.

A coprocess is basically a `./a.sh &` but with the input and output redirected to anonymous pipes. The pipe fds are placed in `${COPROC[@]}` array. If you don't have new enough bash, you can use named pipes instead.

What is done here:

1. You start the script in a coprocess. Its output gets queued to a pipe that's not used yet.
2. You obtain the forked PID from `${!}`.
3. You set a trap to kill the spawned script when the reader terminates.
4. You start a new sed process that reads the script output from the pipe at fd `${COPROC[0]}` and prepends the pid to it.

Note that `sed` itself would block the script, so you need to fork it as well. And since it needs to access the pipe, you can't fork it separately. Instead, we fork the whole function.

The trap makes sure that the spawned script will be killed when you kill the spawned function. Thanks to that, you can do something like:

```
prepend_pid ./a.sh &
spid=$!
sleep 4
kill ${spid}
```

without worrying that `./a.sh` will keep running in the background with no output.